# Inserting the image name into the database using file upload method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I had previously mentioned about my registration code. I now want to save the image name into the database.The image is to be uploaded using file upload. The validation is done using jquery and the form has to be submitted using ajax.Now i had read that file uploads cannot be performed using ajax.And that is the problem with my code.

Following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
function ValidateEmail(email) {
    var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|  (([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return expr.test(email);
 };



 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#submit').on('click', function() {
//e.preventDefault();

    valid = true;   
    if ($('#name').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your name");
        //$('#errorMsg1').css('color','red');
        //$('#errorMsg1').html('Please enter your name');
        //document.getElementById("errorMsg1").innerHTML = "You must enter a     name";

        valid = false;
    }

    if ($('#email').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your email");
        //$('#errorMsg2').css('color','red');
        //$('#errorMsg2').html('Please enter your emailid');
        //document.getElementById("errorMsg2").innerHTML = "You must enter a email";
         valid = false;
    }
    if (!ValidateEmail($("#email").val())) {
        alert("Invalid email address.");
        //document.getElementById("errorMsg2").innerHTML = "Invalid email address.";
    }

if ($('#bday').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your birth date");
        //$('#errorMsg3').css('color','red');
        //$('#errorMsg3').html('Please enter your birth date');
        //document.getElementById("errorMsg3").innerHTML = "You must enter your birth-date";
         valid = false;
    }  
if ($('#gender').val() == '') {
        alert ("please select your gender");
        //$('#errorMsg4').css('color','red');
        //$('#errorMsg4').html('Please select your gender');
        //document.getElementById("errorMsg4").innerHTML = "You must select your gender";


         valid = false;
    }  
if ($('#image').val() == '') {
        alert ("please select an image");
        //$('#errorMsg5').css('color','red');
        //$('#errorMsg5').html('Please select an image');
        //document.getElementById("errorMsg5").innerHTML = "You must select an image";


         valid = false;
    }  
 });   
return false;



 $("#multiform").submit(function (e)
{

var formObj=$(this);
var formURL=formObj.attr("action");
var formData=new formData(this);
$ajax({
 URL:formURL,
type:'POST',
data:formData,
mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
contentType:false,
cache:false,
processData:false,
success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
},
error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
}


});
  e.preventDefault();
e.unbind();
}



);
return true;
$("#multiform").submit();

});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="multiform" id="multiform" action="save_data.php" method="POST"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h4>Name:</h4> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  autofocus>
 <br><br>
<h4>E-mail:</h4> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  autofocus>
 <br><br>
 <h4>Birth-date:</h4> <input type="text" name="bday" id="bday"  autofocus>
 <br><br>
  <h4>Gender:</h4>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"   autofocus>Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"  autofocus>Male
      <br><br>
    Select Image:<input type="file" name="image" id="image"><br><br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">






</form>




</body>
</html>
```

save_data.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $bday = $gender = $image="";

//$image=$_FILES["image"]["name"]; 



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
 $bday=$_POST["bday"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$image =$_POST["image"];



$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mvs1";
$password = "";
$dbname="scootsy_categories";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "INSERT INTO user_details(name,email,bday,gender,image) VALUES   ('$name','$email','$bday','$gender','$image')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   // echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
//if($name !="" || $email !="" || $bday !=""  || $gender !=""  || $image !=""  )
//{
//  $sql="DELETE FROM user_details where name='$name' || email='$email' ||   bday='$bday' || gender='$gender' || image='$image'";
 //}







$conn->close();



}
echo "Successful";
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please ignore all the comments within the code, i have been trying to do a variety of stuffs, and some of them didn't work, so i have kept them as comments

Comment: Try to remove all "useless" code. Check [mcve]. Nobody will scroll and analyze all that. As it currently stands, all you'll get are downvotes and flags for closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save images into a database, but you can save the path url and before you save the image into a folder with php. For do this, you have to modify your ajax code and your php file because for do all this, we have to use $_FILES for extract the name, type, size and temp_folder for move it into a filder.

1. Rewrite your ajax code.
2. Get with $_FILES the properties of the file

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('body').on('click','#submit', function() {
           $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'save_data.php',
               data: new FormData($('#your_id_form')[0]),
               contentType:false,
               cache:false,
               processData:false,
               success:function(upload) {
                   $('#multiform').html(upload):
               }
           });         
       });
   </script>

   <form id="your_id_form" method="POST" action="save_data.php">
       <input type="name" placeholder="Your name">
       <input type="file" name="file">
       <input type="button" id="submit">
   </form>
   <div id="multiform"></div>
   ```

   `//save_data.php

       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $file_name = $_FILES['file'];
       $file_size = $file_name['size'];
       $file_type = $file_name['type'];
       $file_tmp  = $file_name['tmp_name'];
           list($name,$type) = explode('/',$file_type);
           $save_temp = $file_tmp;
           //create a new folder named images into your root page
           $new_path  = 'images/'.$name.$type;
           //we move the file from the temporal folder to a new folder
           move_uploaded_file($save_temp, $new_path);
           $file_url = 'images/'.$file_type;
           $sql = "INSERT INTO database (name,file_url) VALUES ('$name', '$new_path')";
           //do stuffs for connect your query to your database

   echo 'Uploaded!';`


   ?>